# Capture click on select element (not option)

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/epq2j1yz/

```
<select>
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
</select>
```

--

```
$("select").on("click", () => { console.log("abc"); })
```

I want add an on click handler to a select  box in a way that the event is captured when I click on the select box, the moment I open the select box and the options are displayed. In the example, the event gets fired only when I select an option. But that is not what I want. I want the event to get fired before I select an option, when I open the select box. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

For this case you have to use on change jquery event.

```
$("select").on("change", () => { console.log("abc"); });
```

Comment: No, this does not work. "Change" gets fired when the select box changes its value, i.e. when I click an option that was not selected before.